Syntax highlighting for Java code seems inconsistent or glitched
When I view the code in Remove duplicate character from a string and keep only single occurrences using recursion , the first few lines look like so:

Notably, the type name String is inconsistently highlighted - appearing plain white in some places and orange in others.
I took this screenshot after I had already edited the post to switch from indented code to code fences, even explicitly adding a java language hint - this had no apparent effect.
I can sort of understand why a parameter type or return type might be highlighted differently from a field, but surely the String in String newStr should have the same highlighting as that in String subs or String remvDupl?

It's missing a space after newStr so HLJS doesn't correctly parse it as a valid variable name. That's the difference between that variable and all the others that are highlighted correctly. Given that, it appears this is solely a HLJS issue with their parsing and not a Stack Exchange-specific issue.

I am voting to close this since such bug reports should go to Highlight.js instead of here. If this is fixed there but not applied here the request should be for Stack Overflow to update the version used.

I changes this to a duplicate closure, as the duplicate target describes how to report bugs to highlight.js. It wouldn't be too unusual for this issue to have already been fixed in highlight.js, but that SE is not using the most recent version. I haven't checked, but that's been the situation with other, previously-reported issues.

In general, the highlighting for Java depends on the Java coding conventions being followed. For example, it is something like this (and I have an example somewhere; I just can't locate it right now. I think there was a reference to a sample question in a comment on Über Meta).

cont' - Or at least it was. It may or may not have changed with a different version of the Weird Syntax Highlighter (or a different configuration of it, if any).

It may not be a bug, but simply how it is: Weird

Java Code Conventions (1997). The closest seems to be "All binary operators, except ., should be separated from their operands by spaces" (I am not sure about the interpretation for assignment).

Though it may be out of date.

Google's Go set the new standard for conventions - by it not being a document but a tool relentlessly enforcing it (gofmt). Java doesn't really have a convention by such modern standards. Certainly not modern Java which has had numerous additions and changes since those very old ideas were put on paper. As such, what should be considered here is what the conventions are of the syntax highlighter. Apparently it wants spaces. Not much of a big deal.
